# "Do something" after set amount of days in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to "do something" after say 7 days has gone by? I have a `books` model and would like to create a new book every 7 days. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a great tool called [Clockwork](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2010/6/30/replace_cron_with_clockwork/) that's just for this purpose. For your example, you'd write something like:

```
every 7.days, 'create_book'
```

(Given a corresponding create_book method)

Here's the repo for it: https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork